# Can a recruiter tell my company I am looking for a new position?

Tags: recruitment, france

I am in a small city of France and I fear that there are not that many recruiters out there.

One of the recruiters is the one who found me my current company. I am not ready to let my company know I am opened for new opportunities.

I know that the recruiter is still in touch with my company. Will he keep it confidential if he finds me in the potential candidates on some job portal? What if I apply for one of his jobs?

Comment: If you are applying for a job that is in a company different from your current one, there is no reason for him to contact your current company - and doing so may breach GDPR (There should be somewhere to say to only contact references is successful)

Answer (score 6):

Any recruiter who is any good will **not** say you are leaving to your current company - this is just not a good business strategy for them. If they did that would you continue with them?

However, it is possible that sometimes things "get back" to your manager through other routes...

Comment: Depends on your definition of 'good'. Good as in honest with morals, they won't. But many recruiters are cut-throat and won't hesitate to contact your boss and start offering suitable candidates for replacement.

Comment: @NibblyPig but recruiters often contact companies with "we have a person X, who might be a good fit for your company" even though there may be no posts advertised...

Comment: Sure, but now they *know* there's a position opening up. They want to get in there first. They'll probably phone and say they're asking for a reference for candidate Joe Bloggs so reception transfer the call to the manager, and pretend to ask for a reference and build rapport before suggesting some similarly qualified candidates they just happen to have.

Comment: I've had this before, years ago. My boss gave me a stack of CVs to review for potential new hire. Buried in the middle of them was my own, at the top its _last updated_ date an unknowing traitor. I was mortified, but the boss took it really well, offering me a small pay rise. I phoned the agent who shrugged it off without a care.

Answer (score 1):

The recruiter would have nothing to gain by telling your current employer that you're looking for a new job.

There isn't some vast, shadowy conspiracy to make life difficult for you by ratting you out to your current employer. The recruiter doesn't care. If anything, he sees you as a potential ally in his/her being able to place you with one of his clients.

Comment: Not only that, but the recruiter then gets to recruit for your replacement at your existing company, so it's win-win for them. I've literally had recruiters place me in a company, then the second I'm out of probation and they've been paid, they get back in touch to find out if I'd be interested in other roles. This makes sense to them, they earn money from people constantly changing jobs, they have zero interest in doing anything that endangers people's ability to do that.